# Changing the Range of a UISlider Programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uislider

How is it possible to set the min max ranges of the UISlider programmatically?

For example (dummy code)

```
UISlider* slider = [[UISlider alloc] init];
slider.min = -3;
slider.max = 3;
```

EDIT:

So I have the following:

```
sl.minimumValue = 5;
NSLog(@"MIN VAL: %d", sl.minimumValue);
```

This doesn't work, I still get it logging the value 0. Is this because I have set values in interface builder?

Comment: i advice to you always set ANY values by code. also remember        `sl.minimumValue` is float.
   `NSLog(@"MIN VAL: %f", sl.minimumValue);` that should work.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your reply. I create the slider in interface builder but I can;t set its values programatically...

Comment: just try to change code to this `sl.minimumValue = 5.0f;
NSLog(@"MIN VAL: %f", sl.minimumValue);`. also start app with brackpoint in this part of code.

Comment: I cannot get it to work, it seems IB overrides my code...I am placing this in the viewDidLoad method

Comment: it can't be. xib loads on init method. viewDidLoad is calling after. did you connect your slider to code in IB?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is it.

```
UISlider* slider = [[UISlider alloc] init];
slider.minimumValue = -3.0f;
slider.maximumValue = 3.0f;
```

Comment: this doesn't work. it is loading the min max values from interface builder...how do i stop it from doing that

Answer (score 2):

In the case **updating selected values** of **IBOutlet**-ed RangeSeekSlider

```
rangeSeekSlider.selectedMinValue = 10.0
rangeSeekSlider.selectedMaxValue = 100.0
rangeSeekSlider.setNeedsLayout()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Add a frame where you want to place the slider. This will place it at (x,y) = 0,0     
with a height of 10 and width of 200

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 10.0);

// sliderAction will respond to the updated slider value
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

// Set minimum and maximum value
slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
slider.maximumValue = 50.0;
slider.continuous = YES;

// Initial value
slider.value = 25.0;

// Add slider to view
[self.view addSubview:slider];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 :

```
self.yourSlider.minimumValue = 0.0
self.yourSlider.maximumValue = 4
self.yourSlider.value = 0
```