# Using UISlider as UISwitch (Two state object)

Tags: ios, user-interface, xamarin.ios, uislider, uiswitch

Note: I'm using Monotouch.

I'd like to know if there's a way to use `UISlider` object as an `UISwitch` object. I mean... I want to use the `UISlider` object only in two states (100% or 0%), and I want to block the other states for the user interaction.

I'm trying to do this because I'm developing a software, and it'll control the illumination of some modules. The problem is that there are modules with dimmer (0% through 100%), and non-dimmer modules (0% or 100% value), and I need the `UISlider` working as I mentioned before in the second case.

The problem with the `UISwitch` is that is a totally different component visually, it's not as thin as the slider and i cannot put icons representing the state of ON and OFF (beside it as in the attached photo), and I was wondering that maybe the UI is gonna be a mess with slider and switchs...

[image]

Comment: Do you want the slider at empty to represent off and full to represent on? Are you going to let them slide it or just tap?

Comment: 1st question: Exactly. 2nd question: Maybe just tap to go to another state (i think it's easier).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the target/action of the `UISlider` and programmatically force it to one of the extremes.

I'd set `continuous` to `NO`, and then animate the slider to the closer end (to make it more apparent to the user what is happening).

**Edit:**
per your question, here's a typical mechanism to animate a value:

```
UISlider *slider;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 // seconds
                 animations:^{
                   slider.value = (YES) ? 1.0 : 0.0; // modify this line as appropriate
                 }];
```

Comment: Do you know how can I do this animation? Is it something done in the object library?

Comment: response added to answer: use `+[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]`

Answer (score 1):

if you use IB you can set the min and max values for a slider, so use 0, 1 respectively.  or you can do it in code, see below:

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029644/changing-the-range-of-a-uislider-programatically)

or coppied and pasted from that post:

```
UISlider* slider = [[UISlider alloc] init];
slider.minimumValue = -3.0f;
slider.maximumValue = 3.0f;
```

its a float value hence the 3.0f loat

Comment: Won't it just stretch the scale? I mean it doesn't use integers so your slider would return a range of values between 0 and 1. I think he's looking to make it snap to 0 or 1.

Comment: ya good point, but i would think u could round it up or down and if you did it programmatically it should work.  but i havnt tried it and maybe its not possible.  however i dont see any other way to accomplish this except to maybe know ahead of time whats needed then load a slider or a switch based on the situation.

Comment: I was just asing about the UISlider object funcionality. Otherwise, to the user interaction, I'll do something like: More than 50% (send command on), less than 50% (send command off).

Comment: also when your doing that set the slider value to 1 or 0 so that it actually looks like its slid the whole way

Answer (score 1):

I think you want your slider to snap to 0 or 1. Use the code found [in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370342/implementing-steps-snapping-uislider) and set your values appropriately. Funny coincidence, I just finished coding this upself for a snapping slider not 10 minutes ago. To save clicking, here's the code you want, copy/pasted from that question:

```
-(IBAction)valueChanged:(id)sender {
    // This determines which "step" the slider should be on. Here we're taking 
    //   the current position of the slider and dividing by the `self.stepValue`
    //   to determine approximately which step we are on. Then we round to get to
    //   find which step we are closest to.
    float newStep = roundf((questionSlider.value) / self.stepValue);

    // Convert "steps" back to the context of the sliders values.
    self.questionSlider.value = newStep * self.stepValue;
}
```